# What is implied when the spectrum of a star has deep absorption lines at the frequency of a level 1 hydrogen transition line?

Tags: particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, astrophysics, astronomy, physical-chemistry

I think this means that their are many adsorptions occurring at the lower wavelengths. But why could this be? What does this say about the star? What I was thinking is that it could imply that the star is surrounded by a large amount of hydrogen gas (a hydrogen gas cloud) but that doesn't seem to sound right.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

why doesn't your intuition sound right? Stars get their energy from fusing hydrogen together , and our star (sun) has a hydrogen cloud surrounding it...[image]

For absorption lines the light Ray's have to pass through "something"

I think my answer is pretty close. :)